# rails add image inside the map method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a link separated by comma in my view like the following:

```
<%= raw post.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t, tag_path(t) }.join(' ') %>
```

I want the `image_tag` instead of `string`.

For example, I got the result:

```
Book, Sports, World
```

Instead of the above `links of String` I want to show the `image of Book, image of Sports, image of world.`

How can I achieve in rails. Thanks

Comment: You could use `{|t| image_tag(tag_path(t))}`

Comment: How's the image for every determined, is it accessible via the tag?

Comment: Yes, it is accessible via the tag. Thanks @thomasklemm

Comment: Thanks @rubyracer How can i remove the quotes and commas?

Comment: @rubyracer I want the image as a link as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something along the lines of

```
<% post.tag_list.each do |tag| %>
  <%= link_to image_tag(tag.image_url), tag_path(tag) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you thomas. If I can't access the image via tag. Is any other alternatives there? Can I do anything like If `tag == 'Sports'` then display sports image like that?

Comment: Well, which way do you generate the path/url to your image?

Comment: I did like `<%= image_tag "health_icon.png", size: "30x30" %>`. But If you have any better option please let me know.